# VS Code Python unittest: No tests discovered even when following the tutorial

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow the Python tutorial as per https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/unit-testing#_create-tests. But every time no tests are discovered and neither I can execute the test file manually: 0 tests are run.

[image: the workspace structure and files content]
I have tried doing that on my working workspace and then attempted to start everything from scratch but both times the results are the same. Also, I have tried using Remote - WSL on VS Code Insiders and the classic VS Code:

> ```
> Version: 1.34.0-insider (user setup)
> Commit: 473af338e1bd9ad4d9853933da1cd9d5d9e07dc9
> Date: 2019-05-01T00:22:05.899Z
> Electron: 3.1.8
> Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
> Node.js: 10.2.0
> V8: 6.6.346.32
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
>
> Version: 1.33.1 (user setup)
> Commit: 51b0b28134d51361cf996d2f0a1c698247aeabd8
> Date: 2019-04-11T08:27:14.102Z
> Electron: 3.1.6
> Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
> Node.js: 10.2.0
> V8: 6.6.346.32
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
> ```

**basic.py**

```py
    def just_method(number):
        return number

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print just_method(42)
```

**basictest.py**

```py
    import unittest
    import basic

    class MyBasicTests(unittest.TestCase):

        def default_number(self):
            number = 42
            self.assertEqual(basic.just_method(number), number)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

**settings.json** content:

```py
    {
        "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
            "-v",
            "-s",
            ".",
            "-p",
            "*test.py"
        ],
        "python.testing.pyTestEnabled": false,
        "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
        "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
        "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python"
    }
```

Could you please help to identify the problem? I am pretty sure it is located somewhere on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File names and method names are important for test discovery. If you follow the tutorial to the letter this should work.

If you want to use your own code instead, try changing `default_number` to `test_default_number`, and `basictest.py` to `test_basic.py`.

Comment: Thank you, @Björn! After I just copy-pasted the code and file names from the tutorial, of course, everything works fine. In fact, I wonder why "*test.py" was not able to find file **basictest.py**

Comment: Thank you again, I have figured out how this works! The thing was, additionally, that I have a workspace with a parent folder in it. And for some reason, no settings of the test folder path can make this work.

Answer (score -1):

In order to inherit a class, you have to use the super() method.

```py
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, *args): # '*args' for arguments to this class
        super().__init__(self, *args) # '*args' for arguments to pass in the parent class's __init__ method
```

in your case:

```py
# put imports here
class MyBasicTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def test_this(self):
        number = 20
        self.assertEqual(number, basic.just_method(number))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I am following the official guidelines and moreover, the unittest reference does not mention the necessity of the base class initialization: <https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example>. Still, I tried your variant and it does not work as well.

Comment: Indeed don't need to do super(). But the important bit is in the guidelines you posted: `A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three individual tests are defined with *methods whose names start with the letters test*. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.` (See my answer below)